# jQuery $(this) on child selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Building a similar setup to Twitters Follow/Unfollow button and can't quite get it working with jQuery.

Complete so far;
 - jQuery on a single **known ID** for a `<button>` for updating all the details needed
 - API powering the server side logic
 - Everything else server side is working perfectly

Can't figure out;
 - How to expand the functionality I have for a single known ID to **multiple unknown IDs**.

Here's the code I have working for the known single point;

```
//Update Links
                            $("#api-follow-button").html(buttonText);
                            $("#api-follow-button").attr("currentState", currentState);
```

The above code is wrapped in a function with a whole host of other code which is triggered by;

```
$(document).on("click", "#api-follow-button", followButton());
```

This works perfect as I know the ID. The challenge being, how to expand this when the  ID that is to be updated is unknown?

I've tested so many variations using `$(this)` and I'm not getting anything working. I'm sure I'm just missing something blindingly obvious here.

So imagine this code as an example;

```
<button id="button-idxxx">Text 1</button>
<button id="button-idxxx">Text 2</button>
<button id="button-idxxx">Text 3</button>
```

Then whenever someone clicks on one of the `<button>`, then the 'Text X' would change to something else

Ideas?

Comment: you really shouldn't change ids.

Comment: I'm not changing IDs. The IDs are pulled from the database so they are unique. I.e. think of a Twitter Handle being one of the IDs

Comment: Try with a class instead of an id. that way the class can be consistent and the ID can change.

Comment: so `button-idxxx` would be the same as `api-follow-button`? In that case, what do you use for the selector to attach the `followButton()` if the ids are different? Jorge is right, you probably want to use classes.

Comment: Can you use the [Attribute Starts With Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) like in my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/vx3vyqev/1/) here? (See the answer posted below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all. The code in the fiddle for `alert($(this).text());` works perfectly but when doing anything like updating the text on the page this didn't seem to work for some reason. With a bit of fiddling around based on the helpful info here's what I came up with which worked;

**HTML Buttons**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" id="api-follow-button-uniqueID-xxx" currentState="NotFollowing">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" id="api-follow-button-uniqueID-xxx" currentState="NotFollowing">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" id="api-follow-button-uniqueID-xxx" currentState="NotFollowing">
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $(document).on('click', '[id^="api-follow-button"]', function followButton(e) {

                    e.preventDefault();

                    var currentState = $(this).attr("currentState");

//This line below ensures that you can then use the ID selector to update the relevant part of the HTML as needed, see note below
                    var buttonID = $(this).attr("id");


                            var buttonText = "";
                            var currentState = "";

                                buttonText = "Unfollow";
                                currentState = "Following";

                            //Update Links
//This part from comment above
                            $("button[id=" + buttonID + "]")
                                    .html(buttonText)
                                    .attr("currentState", currentState);

                        });
                    }

                });
            });
```

Looks like it's all done what is needed now. I've removed a bunch of code from above to simplify things

Thanks all

Comment: This is a bit confusing. I'm hoping you can shed some light on it for me. Why are you retrieving the `currentState` in the second line of the handler and then clearing it (after reinitializing it?) on the fifth line of the handler?

Comment: Ah, that is because some of the code I've removed isn't there. I have a couple of 'if' statements which do different things based on the initial 'currentState' variable. I.e. if (currentState === 'Following') {//do something} - - and - - if (currentState === 'NotFollowing') {//do something else} - - Basically the buttonText and currentState attributes are updated based on the previous currentState when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

This `$(this)` you mention probably works correct (*although you did not post your relevant code*).

The error seems to be in `$(document).on("click", "#api-follow-button", followButton());` where the `()` should be missing from the `followButton` method.

So try with

```
$(document).on('click', '[id^="button-id"]', followButton);
```

(*the `[id^="button-id"]` selector matches elements with an id attribute that starts with `button-id` text*)

Your `followButton` should be something like this

```
function followButton(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // define buttonText and currentState here 
    // unless they come from elsewhere
    $(this)
        .html(buttonText)
        .attr("currentState", currentState);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

(Thinking out loud) You could potentially use the [Attribute Starts With Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) found in the linked article. With this selector, you can select all the buttons that may contain a specific prefix (i.e. `button-id`) from your example without knowing the entire `id` of the element.

**From the attribute starts-with selector docs:**

> **Description**: Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string.

For example:

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
 $(document).on('click', '[id^="button-id"]', function () {
   alert($(this).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="button-id12345">
Text 1
</button>
<button type="button" id="button-id678910">
Text 2
</button>
<button type="button" id="button-id1112131415">
Text 3
</button>
```